# my knoppix audio test out good, with Kmix, but it's not there with media player

Tags: linux, audio

I'm running knoppix 7.4 if i setup the sound in kmix it works. if i play something with vlc there's no sound  and the speaker icon at the bottom right corner of the screen has a red x in front of it and nothing seems to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

different programs use different default output devices.

Check audio device settings in `vlc`, try the most promising ones.
Then i usually start `aumix` in a terminal. It's a textbased mixer.
Use `<-` `->` arrows to select output and `up` `down` arrows
to increase / decrease volume. **And** use `m` to mute / unmute 
this channel.

For some reason some channels just hangup and sound is gone ...
Doing this procedure for every channel is fast and usually works,
although it's a "brute force" or killing-the-symptoms solution.